# How to get proper stack labels with 'datetime' axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

First off, the fiddle to my question is here: http://jsfiddle.net/pfifas/aTh7F/

## The problem

I want to display the sum of the values of all series at each point on the horizontal axis as stack labels above each stack. Because I have negative stacks and I do not want to display positive and negative totals above and beneath separately, I set up a formatter function manually (lines 42 through 50 in the fiddle). The stack labels that I want should be the sum over **all** values at a given point, i.e. the sum of the positive stacks minus the sum of all negative stacks. E.g. if the data series at the first point is

```
data: [1,-2,3,4]
```

I would like the stack label to display a "6" above the stacked bar. My formatter function works fine with data series of the sort

```
data: [1,-2,3,4]
```

But once I add a date variable to each series like

```
data: [
[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 4],
[Date.UTC(2010, 3, 1), 15],
[Date.UTC(2010, 6, 1), 17],
[Date.UTC(2010, 9, 1), 10]
]
```

the stack labels are not displayed anymore. I think I am making a mistake with the indexing of the array in the formatter function. How do I have to change the indexing to achieve the correct result?

On a different note, where can I learn more about which variables are available inside the formatter environment and how to handle them in highcharts?

### Edit:

In response to Onkloss answer, I should highlight that this issue is related to setting the axis to type `'datetime'`, not to whether the array of data is multidimensional (as the previous question title was suggesting).

Comment: You want the positive total at the top of each column, but not the negative total at the bottom?

Comment: Ondkloss, no I want the positive minus the negative at the top and nothing at the bottom. I hope my edit makes this more comprehensible. It's really just that I do not know how to correctly access the correct elements in the arrays of data I am passing on to the formatter function (see fiddle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the use of `this.x` here:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    sum += series[i].yData[this.x];
}
```

For "normal" x-axis types this works well since you can open the `yData` by index. In your case it will end up trying to find something like `series[0].yData[1262304000000]`, which won't work.

I'm not aware of any easy way to find the relationship between the timestamp `this.x` and which index that has on the x-axis. My solution uses another for loop to compare the timestamp from `this.x` with the `xData` array, and if it matches we use the data in the sum, as shown in this updated `formatter`:

```
formatter: function () {
    // If doing negative, ignore
    if(this.total <= 0)
        return;

    var sum = 0;
    var series = this.axis.series;

    for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < series[i].xData.length; j++) {
            if(series[i].options.type == 'column' && series[i].xData[j] == this.x) {
                sum += series[i].yData[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

This [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aTh7F/3/) shows it in action.

Comment: Like a charm. So it was not only the fact that my array has two "columns", but also that I had a datetime axis which leads `this.x` to return the value in milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, correct! Your main problem was that `this.x` no longer returns numbers that are nicely 0-indexed, so that they can be used for `yData[index]`. "Two columns" in the `data` array would still work if the `x` values were 0, 1, 2...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking for correctly, the following formatter function should work:

```
        formatter: function () {
            return this.total >= 0 ?this.total : null ;
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aTh7F/1/

As to the available options in the formatter function, http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.dataLabels.formatter should help.  But, I tend to just put a breakpoint in the function and inspect what `this` is. :)

Comment: Barbara, sorry for the verbose and somewhat ambiguous question. So, your answer gives me stack labels that are the sum of all positive stacks. But what I really want is this number minus the negative stacks. That's why I was summing over all values in my initial formatter. I should edit the question to make this more comprehensible...